# R data.table %like% with logical AND

Tags: r, data.table, sql-like

I am trying to build a Shiny app that is a search engine.
I am returning a data.table based on the search keywords:

```
DT <- data.table(field = c("A_B_C","A_C_D","A_D_A","B_A_D","B_C_F","B_D_K"))

DT[field %like% "A|B"]
```

The above returns all fields containing A OR B.
If I want to have A & B:

```
DT[field %like% "A"][field %like% "B"]
```

Is there a syntax that will allow me to do the above for any number of keywords.
Something like:

```
DT[field %like% "A & B & C"]
```

Comment: sounds like a good FR for `%inlike%`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there are only two elements, compare them separately, then do a `&` and subset the dataset

```
DT[field %like% "A" & field %like% "B"]
#  field
#1: A_B_C
#2: B_A_D
```

If there are many strings to compare use `Reduce` with `Map`.

```
DT[Reduce(`&`, Map(`%like%`, list(field), c("A", "B")))]
#    field
#1: A_B_C
#2: B_A_D
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use *Perl-style* regex, in combination with `grepl` inside your `data.table`:

```
pat <- "(?=.*A)(?=.*B)"
DT[grep(pat, field, perl = TRUE),]
#   field
#1: A_B_C
#2: B_A_D
```

Comment: Could also show how to move from a query to that pattern, like `query = "A & B";
library(magrittr);
pat = query %>% 
    sub("^\\s*", "(?=.*", x = .) %>%
    sub("\\s*$", ")", x = .) %>%
    sub("\\s*&\\s*", ")(?=.*", x = .)
`

Comment: With a vector of search terms like `terms <- c("A", "B")`, you can use `DT[grepl(paste(sprintf("(?=.*%s)", terms), collapse=""), field, perl=TRUE)]`.